# Should `Hooks` can be used as replacement of `Redux` in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have seen [React.js 16.8.x](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html) release notes. They introduced **Hooks** in react.

I have knowledge on `Redux` but new to `Hooks`. `Redux` is used to maintain whole application in store So now question is that **Should we use react `Hooks` as complete replacement of `redux`**?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 3):

React Hooks let you use state and lifecycles method inside your functional components. The main advantage is you don't need to declare classes and still setting and getting state variables and life cycles method is possible

There are other features too https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Or refer to hooks lauch video on YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

## For first question:

Hooks allow you to access state and Lifecycle methods in a functional component, so you don't need to write class component.

### Hooks are not alternative to redux,

- Hooks state is limited to component whereas Redux Store can be accessed in entire app
- Hooks does not maintain single store like redux does.

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.
Check below link,

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html